# How to remove a not working network drive with batch?

Tags: batch-file, network-drive

I am trying to remove a mapped network drive and add it back again.
Users who have problems with their mapped drives, can use this script to fix their not working network-drive so I dont have to do it by hand. Also, I am flushing the DNS since it could be the source of the issue the user has.

I am not that good at batch and don't understand, why my script ain't working. Hope someone can help here.

In response to @Gerhard: I make it this "complicated" since windows sometimes stops deleting mapped drives since it runs background tasks on it. And to make sure, the Drive gets deleted, I made this loop.

```
@echo off
::flushing DNS may also help with some problems a user might have
ipconfig /flushdns

::while the X drive exists, it the script tries to delete it till it succeeds. 
:while
IF exist "X:\*" (
    net use X: /delete
    if exist "X:\*"(
        goto  :while
    )
) ELSE (
    if not exist "X:\*" (
        net use X: \\<Domain> /persistent:yes
    )
)
```

Comment: Your `if`/`else` syntax is wrong; type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and compare. *N. B.:* To check a (root) directory for existence, `if exist "X:\*"` is more reliable than `if exist "X:\"` (particularly when it comes to junctions, symbolic links and stuff like that)…

Comment: When you design a script you should not make assumptions, and try to run through in a logical order. So your first task should be to determine if your end user has the mapped drive `X:`. Then you should verify that the location it is mapped to is the location you are expecting it to be. If both of those are confirmed, then you should determine if the drive is accessible/working. Only at this point should you consider trying to re-establish the mapped drive and its connection.

Comment: What about using just the following command lines in your batch file? 1. `@echo off`, 2. `%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe /flushdns >nul 2>nul` (requires elevated privileges of a local administrator) 3. `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe X: /delete /yes >nul 2>nul` (the option `/yes` results in network connection deletion even if `X:` is currently in use), 4. `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe X: \\%USERDOMAIN%\ShareName /persistent:yes`

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement is not correct. The parentheses needs ro be on the same line as `else`. As in `) else (`.
You also do not need to parenthesize each `if` statement either. You needed a space between `\(` in the statement `if exist X:\(` and lastly, you do not need to check `if not exist` as your `else` statement already confirmed it does not:

```
@echo off
ipconfig /flushdns
:while
if exist X:\* (
    net use X: /delete
    if exist X:\* goto  :while
  ) else (
    net use X: \\<domain> /persistent:yes
)
```